# WordPress Dashboard leave me alone

Tags: php, wordpress

I have inherited a website for a local theatre group which has been created in WordPress. The owners would like to keep it this way as they can tinker with it in the dashboard. I however am used to developing in Codeigniter and like to do the coding myself and not via the dashboard. The dashboard for me makes things more difficult.

I feel as though I have little control over how my pages are structured since I cant find the PHP file which structures my pages

Is there a way around this? All the guides I have read all speak of using the dashboard.

Does anyone know a good place I can get started?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/

Comment: This is confusing.  If you are used to doing without the dashboard, why the trouble "find[ing] the PHP file which structures [the] pages"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience I've found it best to leave content management to your content management system.  **What** is displayed on your page, like text, titles and images, should be done in the backend of WordPress.

For selecting how individual pages are structured I would recommend using a [Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates).  Page Templates will allow you to select a different template for specific pages.

For modifying the layout of standard WordPress pages, I would start with reading over the [Template Heirarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) page in the WP codex.  This will help you understand which template files are being called during the rendering of certain pages.

Another thing that has helped me **immensely** has been the Show Current Template plugin by JOTAKI.  This plugin lists the template files currently being used on the frontend admin bar.  This tool has cut my theme development time by approximately 15%.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) would be the place for you then. You can't change the WordPress code through the Dashboard itself (nor should you) but WordPress does allow you to see and change the files used by plugins and themes if you wish to change them. For example, if you want to change the way the pages look you can go to Appearance/Editor in the Admin Dashboard where you will be able to see and edit the theme files though I'd recommend writing a [child-theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) in this case. Playing around with the WordPress theme files is not nearly as difficult as it looks.

Also, as others have mentioned, the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) is very useful in explaining pretty much anything about the CMS in very simple speak.